# How to get local repository location from Maven 3.0 plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, aether

How to get local repository location (URI) from within Maven 3.x plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Aether as described in [this blog post](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/how-to-use-aether-in-maven-plugins/).

```
/**
 * The current repository/network configuration of Maven.
 *
 * @parameter default-value="${repositorySystemSession}"
 * @readonly
 */
private RepositorySystemSession repoSession;
```

now get the local Repo through [`RepositorySystemSession.getLocalRepository()`](http://sonatype.github.com/sonatype-aether/apidocs/org/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession.html#getLocalRepository%28%29):

```
LocalRepository localRepo = repoSession.getLocalRepository();
```

[`LocalRepository`](http://sonatype.github.com/sonatype-aether/apidocs/org/sonatype/aether/repository/LocalRepository.html) has a [`getBasedir()`](http://sonatype.github.com/sonatype-aether/apidocs/org/sonatype/aether/repository/LocalRepository.html#getBasedir%28%29) method, which is probably what you want.

Comment: @DmytroChyzhykov no idea, you should ask a separate question

Comment: at least with Maven 3.6.* it does not work with those JavaDoc annotations anymore, but with the `@Parameter` annotation from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911656/1915920

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me in Maven v3.6.0:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${localRepository}", readonly = true, required = true)
private ArtifactRepository localRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sean Patrick Floyd provided a solid answer.

This solution doesn't require the injection of the Properties into your instance fields.

```
@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
   MavenProject project=(MavenProject)getPluginContext().get("project");
   Set<Artifact> arts=project.getDependencyArtifacts();
   Set<String> localRepoSet = new HashSet<>();
   for (Artifact art : arts) {
        if (art.getScope().equals(Artifact.SCOPE_COMPILE)) {
            Path path = Paths.get(art.getFile().getAbsolutePath());

            String removal = art.getGroupId().replace(".", "/") + "/" + art.getArtifactId() + "/"
                    + art.getVersion();
            String localRepo = path.getParent().toAbsolutePath().toString().replace(removal, "");
            localRepoSet.add(localRepo);
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the possible locations of all of your direct dependencies.

**Tested in Maven 3.X.X**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get local repository location from settings:

```
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${settings}", readonly = true )
private Settings settings;

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
  final File localRepository = new File(settings.getLocalRepository());

  ...
}
```

It works in maven-3x.